# Cannot start webpack-dev-server - MODULE NOT FOUND

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, material-design, webpack-dev-server

(I'm attempting to follow [this tutorial](https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting-started))

When I  run `npm start` I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\Projects\Websites\project\project> npm start 
> PROJECT@0.0.0 start C:\Users\user\Desktop\Projects\Websites\project\project
> webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js --open

'find_dp0' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:772:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:27)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I think the main issue is that it's looking for the `webpack-dev-server` module in my `C:/` drive since the error is saying:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js'
```

Why would it be looking there for the module and not in the local `node_modules` folder? This is at least what I think is causing the issue, maybe it is something else though?

I couldn't find this same error online anywhere else (where it was looking in the users `C:/` drive). I am working in Visual Studio Community 2019. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**`package.json`:**

```
{
    "name": "drewpel.com",
    "description": "drewpel.com",
    "author": "James Pelusi",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js --open",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test script was specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "4.17.1",
        "morgan": "1.10.0",
        "pug": "3.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "css-loader": "4.2.2",
        "extract-loader": "5.1.0",
        "file-loader": "6.0.0",
        "sass": "1.26.10",
        "sass-loader": "10.0.1",
        "webpack": "4.44.1",
        "webpack-cli": "3.3.12",
        "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.0"
    }
}
```

**`webpack.config.js`:**

```
module.exports = [{
    entry: './css/index.scss',
    output: {
        // This is necessary for webpack to compile
        // But we never use style-bundle.js
        filename: 'style-bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: 'bundle.css',
                        },
                    },
                    { loader: 'extract-loader' },
                    { loader: 'css-loader' },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            // Prefer Dart Sass
                            implementation: require('sass'),

                            // See https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/804
                            webpackImporter: false,
                        },
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
}];
```

Answer (score 5):

```
"start": "webpack serve --config webpack.config.js --open"
```

change the package.json start to this above . I hope it will work

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution for me.